# Use common tables in two select statements just one time

Tags: sql

I have two select statements with two common or two uncommon tables 
and i'm taking a union of these two statements but how can i use common tables in 
both statements just one time

```
select * from (select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 
on t2.id = t1.id_fk
join table3 t3
on t3.id=t2.id_fk
join table4 t4
on t4.id=t3.id_fk
union
select *
from table1_arc t1
join table2_arc t2 
on t2.id = t1.id_fk
join table3 t3
on t3.id=t2.id_fk
join table4 t4
on t4.id=t3.id_fk) 
order by 1
```

Now see

> table 3
>   and 
>   table 4

these tables used two times in both select statements.
Is there any way so that i can use them only once

Comment: Thanks everyone. It works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 
        ON t2.id = t1.id_fk
    union
    SELECT *
    FROM table1_arc t1
    JOIN table2_arc t2 
        ON t2.id = t1.id_fk
) A
JOIN table3 t3
    ON t3.id = A.id_fk
JOIN table4 t4
    ON t4.id = t3.id_fk
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to just reference them once then it would be:

```
select *
from (select *
     from table1 t1
     join table2 t2 
     on t2.id = t1.id_fk
     union all
     select *
     from table1_arc t1
     join table2_arc t2 
     on t2.id = t1.id_fk) as Main
join table3 t3
on t3.id=Main.id_fk
join table4 t4
on t4.id=t3.id_fk
```

Comment: @sagi Must be an ArchiveDateTime or EditDateTime in there somewhere which means the rows will be unique. So UNION ALL makes it more efficient because it doesn't attempt to dedupe the results.

Comment: I know what `UNION ALL` does, but how can you decide 'there's got to be an ArchieveDateTime' ?

Comment: @sagi, archive table is to record who change a row and when. Might be that their isn't a datetime in there, but that would be a different problem.

Comment: @sagi, and there probably is a unique ID on the archive table too. I know I I'm doing a little overreach here, but the guy is learning and most likely will not end up with "SELECT *" and will likely need the UNION ALL.

Comment: Data is not unique in table1 and table1_arc,
table2 and table2_arc 
table1 and table2 have recent data 
and table1_arc and table2_arch have archived data

Comment: @DevUzair use "UNION" if you want to dedup your results and "UNION ALL" if you want to keep the duplicates.

Comment: @JBrooks what we need to change in case i have to use pivot and group by clause in both selects 
which groups columns from outside tables 
like from table 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work if the ID's from the two tables can have the same values such as auto-generated integers.

```
select * 
  from (
     select *,
            T2.ID QueryFk1, 1 QueryKey,
        from table1 t1
        join table2 t2 
          on t2.id = t1.id_fk
  union
  select *,
            T2.ID QueryFk2, 2 QueryKey,
     from table1_arc t1
     join table2_arc t2 
       on t2.id = t1.id_fk
) A
   join table3 t3
     on (t3.id=A.QueryFk1 And A.QueryKey = 1) Or
        (t3.id=A.QueryFk2 And A.QueryKey = 2)
   join table4 t4
     on t4.id=t3.id_fk
   order by 1
```